# 2013 bmw 328i xdrive tail light seal

Tags: electrical, bmw, tail-lights, seal, 328i

I’m taking on water in the lid of my trunk. I investigated and it seams water is coming in through my inner tail lights. I removed the assembly and it appears the corner of the seal on both sides is missing. How do I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Just looking around searching for this issue, it seems you can get replacement seals, and sealing washers.

this link (https://bmwrepairguide.com/trunk-leak-tail-light-leak-bmw-e90/) should give you a good overview of what needs to be done (use the blue tabs on top - last one should be the repair steps).

The basic idea is

- remove trunk covers to expose the chassis holes
- check/test where the water gets into the trunk (make sure battery/exposed electronics are covered beforehand)
- remove tail light, check signs of water marks
- replace necessary gaskets/sealing washers

What i'd suggest is to skim through all of the content and see how that applies to your vehicle (you didn't mention if you have a sedan, estate etc) and "wrenching" experience. Check if you have the tools required, if the new seal or sealing washer is available to you (do not rely on that site's recommended part numbers, double check for your specific model, one of the sites i use to identify manufacturer part numbers is https://partsouq.com/ - based on the correct part number you should be able to search for it online). Gather everything and start only then (you don't want to end up with a vehicle half taken apart and find out you forgot about something - this is especially important if you have a daily driver which you may need for work).